# rounded the value of double

Tags: c++, double, rounding, ostream

after searching an answer to my problem I decide to ask.

I was told I need to round the value of double into 3 decimal places.

I need to use this :

```
os.setf(std::ios::fixed,std::ios::floatfield);
os.precision(3);
```

so I am understand I need to create an object of type ostream so I wrote this:

```
ostream os;
os.setf(std::ios::fixed,std::ios::floatfield);
os.precision(3);
double a = 3.12364;
os << a;
```

but there is a compilation error so I changed the first row into :

```
ostream os(NULL);
```

then the compiler shut up, but I know it did not do anything.
so how do I round the value using ostream ?

pay attention I do not want to print. I do not need/want to use cout

Comment: the compiler error: in this context

Comment: "I do not need/want to use cout" What *do* you want to use? That's the central issue here. The target of the output is what needs to replace that `NULL`.

Comment: I need to round, do some operation and only after that to print because there is cases like : 0.0001 that will round to zero that i do not need to print

Comment: Better question for you: *Why* would you round the value using an `ostream` *at all*? if you want the value properly rounded, why not use [`std::round()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)?

Comment: *"but there is a compilation error so I changed the first row into"* - So if you encounter compilation errors you don't understand, you make random changes to your code you also don't understand? Doesn't sound that resonable.

Comment: I was told to use it. do you say it is better not using that and instead using the round method ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to put the double into a `std::string`, use `std::ostringstream` (which is derived from `std::ostream`).

```
ostringstream os;
os.setf(std::ios::fixed,std::ios::floatfield);
os.precision(3);
double a = 3.12364;
os << a;

std::string rounded( os.str() ); // get the result
```

If you want to round it mathematically, then do

```
round( a * 1000 ) / 1000
```

Using a string in the middle of an equation is always a red flag ;v) .

Comment: but I get this error : "aggregate ‘std::ostringstream os’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined"

Comment: @JoeHaring `#include <sstream>`

Comment: Maybe you should mention its C++11 only.

Comment: Why should he? All answers and questions regarding C++ should be treated as C++11 by default.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz C++03 is still widely prevalent, and new users  may not be aware that there's a newer version. Mentioning C++11 would bring their attention to it and maybe encourage them to learn about it more. Besides, if he tries that code and gets an error, it would only serve to confuse him further. To each their own.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not really want to save the result in a string, you could use plain mathematics.

```
#include <cmath>

float myRound(float input) {
    return input > 0
        ? floor(input * 1000 + 0.5) / 1000
        : ceil(input * 1000 + 0.5) / 1000;
}
```

Be aware though, that the result will be incorrect if the multiplication by 1000 causes an overflow. In C++11, you can also make use of [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

Answer (score 0):

First: if you need to use `ostream`, you don't want to round the
value of a double to three decimal places, you want to display
the value with three decimal places.  (To round it, you'd use
`round( value * 100 ) / 100`.)  Second, you usually don't use an
`ostream` object, you use an object of a type derived from
`ostream`: usually an `ofstream` or `ostringstream`.

The question is where you want this rounded value to appear.  If
you need it in a file, then you will use `ofstream`; if you want
it in a string (e.g. to place in a window component), it's
`ostringstream`, and if you just want it to appear on standard
out, just output it to `cout` (which is of a type derived from
`ostream`).

Also, don't forget to restore the flags and the precision when
you're done: `setf` and `precision` make permanent changes to
the underlying stream.